Debug/release is determined incorrectly when using qmake.conf
The project structure looks like this:
- testprjqt (subdirs)
    - test1 (some prj with main.cpp)

File qmake.conf of project testprjqt contains
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
  DEFINES += RELEASE123
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
  DEFINES += DEBUG123
}

I put this code in qmake.conf to make these definitions visible in all subprojects (recursively)  of testprjqt.
main.cpp in test1 contains
#ifdef RELEASE123
    qDebug() << "RELEASE123";
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG123
    qDebug() << "DEBUG123";
#endif

Regardless which configuration (Debug/Release) I use for building testprjqt, DEBUG123 define is always disabled and program (test1) always writes RELEASE123.
I tried to move the defines to testprjqt.pro, but it doesn't work at all (neither DEBUG123 nor RELEASE123). I moved the defines to test1.pro (just to test it) and it worked well.
Could you please explain me why does it not work?
UPD:
Such code in qmake.conf works:
DEFINES_RELEASE += RELEASE123
DEFINES_DEBUG += DEBUG123

The problem is that it was introduced in Qt 5.13.2, but I need my code to be compatible with Qt 5.6.3.

tahat can't work in qmake.conf qmake.conf  content resolved prior to your project and supposed to be persistent while you try to make it dynamic. CONFIG(release, debug|release) checks at moment of qmake execution which debug or release  out of debug and release pair is the last at that moment. As I understand, qmake.conf's point it always same and defined by mkspec. Instead you may want to use include files (.pri files). DEFINES_RELEASE and DEFINES_DEBUG were intentionally intoduced for this (though you might check f older versions had them but didn't document)
